# call linux command with variable argument from python

Tags: python, command-line, command

I am trying to execute a program from python2x.

In terminal, the job will run as:

```
mpirun -np 8 ~/WORK/scf Fe_SCF.inp > Fe_SCF.out
```

Where `Fe_SCF.*`  are input and output in the `CWD`.

Now, I am trying to run this piece from  python script. Since, I have defined them as variable and tried to call as:

```
call(["mpirun -np 8 ~/WORK/scf", scfin,  scfout])
```

Giving Error:

```
  File "./triolith.py", line 38, in <module>
        call(["mpirun -np 8 ~/WORK/scf", scfin,  scfout])
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
        return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Using real filename does not solve the problem either:

```
 call(["mpirun -np 8 ~/WORK/scf", "Fe_SCF.inp",  "Fe_SCF.out"])
```

Which gives error:

```
File "./triolith.py", line 38, in <module>
    call(["mpirun -np 8 ~/WORK/scf", "Fe_SCF.inp",  "Fe_SCF.out"])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have checked and can confirm, using os.system is working with "Real" filename, but not with variable name as:

```
 os.system("mpirun -np 8 ~/WORK/scf scfin" )
```

So, using either of two method, how can I call the program with a variable name as input and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call takes a list, hence your first example should be:

```
cmd = ['/absolute/path/to/mpirun', '-np', '8', '~WORK/scf', var_1]
call(cmd, stdout=var_2, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Comment: hi...thanks for your reply. Its working fine, except the point that var_2 was supposed to be the file to write my output. but this is writing output to stdout.  I have also tried `cmd = [ ...., var_1, ">" , var_2]` which is not working either.

Comment: hd1, 
This is giving me error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at `stdout=var_2`

Comment: hd1, yes...perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

In your latter example using the OS module, you should be able to do:

```
os.system("mpirun -np 8 ~/WORK/scf "+ var_name)
```

To run your function call.

For multiple variables,d o:

```
os.system("mpirun -np 8 ~WORK/scf " + var_1 + " " + var_2)
```